# Datatype or Datastructure to use for checking modified state?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, data-structures

I am looking for appropriate Data Structure or Data type for checking if the value assigned to the variable is modified or not.

For example,

```
   int x = 0;
    .
    .
    .
    x = 2;
    .
    .
    .
    x = 0; 
    .
    .
    .
    if (x = modified?)
```

Here, I do not want to store the variable as global or something. I want to check if its modified or not. I have tried to glean through resources, but I am unable to find anything. Any suggestion or direction will greatly help. I am looking for data type/data structure that is compatible with Microsoft C#.

Comment: It may be helpful to know what the end usage of this would be. You will not find this functionality in a class like `Int32`.

Comment: the usage explanation is pretty complex to explain here, but the overall need is outlined in the question.

Comment: @Josh Why setter combined with boolean property is not enough?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements, something like the following should work. Essentially, keep track of the originally assigned value and compare to the current.

```
public class ModifiableClass
{

    private readonly int _origValue;

    public int Value;


    public ModifiableClass(int initialValue)
    {
        _origValue = Value = initialValue;
    }

    public bool IsModified()
    {
        return Value != _origValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would at least change it to a generic instead.

Comment: This was just an example, but yes to make it more useable this can be converted to be generic.

Comment: this is still, like assigning a global variable and then check if its modified, which I do not want to.

Comment: Then what you are looking for does not exist. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Modifiable<int> modInt = new Modifiable<int>(5);
        modInt.OnModified += (old, val) => { Console.WriteLine("Modified from {0} to {1}", old, val); };
        modInt.SetValue(4);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Modifiable<T>
{
    private T _value;
    public T Value { get { return _value; } }
    public event Action<T,T> OnModified;
    public void SetValue(T newValue)
    {
        var oldVal = _value;
        _value = newValue;
        OnModified?.Invoke(oldVal, _value);
    }
    public Modifiable(T value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value?.ToString();
    }
}
```

Also you can read about [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)